# How do I install Citrix receiver?

Tags: software-installation, 64-bit, citrix, icaclient

Has anyone managed to get the Citrix receiver client (icaclient) working in Ubuntu?

Comment: `package architecture (i386) does not match system (amd64)` Are you installing the i386 package on amd64 system? Sounds fishy but I might be wrong ;)

Comment: There is only an i386 build of citrix receiver and it needs the 32 bit libmotif4 library.  It fails the dependency when you only have the 64 bit present.  Though, as you said maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The detailed guide on install and usage of Citrix Workspace app in Linux I have explained in my blog below which Tested in 20.04 LTS, 20.10, Fedora 32, Fedora 33

https://www.debugpoint.com/2020/10/install-connect-citrix-desktop-ubuntu-linux/

**However, here is a summary of the steps.**

**Install Citrix Workspace App for Fedora, Red Hat, and Other .rpm based distributions**

Download the below .rpm package for 64-bit systems. Go to the below link. Click on RPM Packages, then Red Hat Full Package (self-service support). Then click on Download file under “Citrix Workspace app for Linux (x86_64)”

https://www.citrix.com/downloads/workspace-app/linux/workspace-app-for-linux-latest.html

Open the .rpm package via Software or any package manager for installation. All the dependencies should already be present in your current system.

**Install Citrix Workspace App for Ubuntu, Linux Mint, and Other Debian based distributions**

Download the below .deb package for 64-bit systems. Go to the below link. Click on Debian Packages, then Full Package (self service support). Then click on Download file under “Citrix Workspace app for Linux (x86_64)”

https://www.citrix.com/downloads/workspace-app/linux/workspace-app-for-linux-latest.html

Open the .deb package via Software or any package manager for installation. All the dependencies should already be present in your current system.

After installation, you can visit your Citrix VM page and log in via browser. The .ICA file association would be taken care of by the installer.

Comment: This appears to be a better modern answer, the initial question and answers are quite old.

Answer (score 25):

## How to install Citrix receiver on Ubuntu 14.04 and 16.04

1. Go to [the Citrix receiver for Linux download page](https://www.citrix.com/downloads/citrix-receiver/linux/receiver-for-linux-latest.html) and download the Debian full package. The filename will look like this: `icaclient_13.3.0.344519_amd64.deb`.
2. Open and install the package using the Software Center or `gdebi`.

That's it!

## How to add Google Chrome support

You can open Citrix receiver apps by clicking a link in your browser. You don't need an extension for that.

Just click on the app shortcut in Google Chrome and download the `.ica` file. When it is downloaded, click the arrow next to the filename in the bottom bar of Chrome and choose **"always open files of this type".**

That's it! Next time you click on a Citrix app, it will be started automatically.

## How to add firefox support

In Firefox, go to Tools -> Add-ons -> Plugins, and make sure the "Citrix Receiver for Linux" plugin is set to **"Always Activate"**.

## How to solve SSL error 61

This error happens because Citrix receiver doesn't trust enough certificates. You fix this by adding all the certificates Firefox trusts to Citrix. Just open a terminal and execute the following command.

```
sudo ln -s /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/* /opt/Citrix/ICAClient/keystore/cacerts
```

**(outdated) sources**

- [Ubuntu Community Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CitrixICAClientHowTo#64-bit)
- [Citrix official documentation](http://docs.citrix.com/en-us/receiver/linux/13-3/linux-install.html)
- [SSL error Citrix receiver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/302188/certificate-error-when-using-citrix-receiver)
- [Open Citrix app in Chrome and Chromium browser](https://askubuntu.com/questions/678204/how-to-start-citrix-client-in-chrome-chromium)

Comment: The official documentation works, though I'm disappointed I can't use the .deb Citrix provides.  I do realize that's not an Ubuntu issue, however.  I hope Citrix gets their 64 bit release out...

Comment: @krondor: they don't even release 32 bit software for windows (at least not on client side)

Comment: +1 this worked perfectly on elementary os (ubuntu 14.04) 64 bit.

Comment: I guess this solution is obsolete based on this link: https://www.citrix.com/blogs/2017/03/15/firefox-52-and-citrix-receiver-for-web/

Comment: for 17.10 use these instructions: https://askubuntu.com/questions/302188/certificate-error-when-using-citrix-receiver/971510?s=1|0.0000#971510 to add the right certificate.  Obviously they have provided a `.deb` file for some time now.

Comment: I get an error from this:

`$ sudo gdebi icaclient_13.9.1.6_amd64.deb`
 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done
Reading state information... Done
This package is uninstallable
Dependency is not satisfiable: libwebkit-1.0-2|libwebkitgtk-1.0-0

Answer (score 2):

They now provide a 64-bit version of the `.deb` package. Unfortunately, the 64-bit package checks if the system is a 32-bit system. Obviously, the check fails.

I've modified the package to properly check for 64-bit system (and 32-bit actually for no reason really).

You can find [my modified package here](http://dev.thirteen8.com/files/icaclient_12.1.0_amd64.deb).

It was literally a one character change to `postinst`. Hope this helps somebody.

Oh, please note that you will still need to copy or link to your `certs` directory.

Answer (score 1):

I made sure that I uninstalled the 64 bit package, and dpkg --force-architecture -i libmotif4*i386.deb so that I installed the 32 bit package,http://ftp.au.debian.org/debian/pool/non-free/o/openmotif/libmotif4_2.3.3-5_i386.deb,  you can only have one or the other installed, not both at the same time as far as I know.

My Citrix receiver now functions.
Regards,Tom.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try again with only 32 bit.  I believe I had gone through this without a fix, are you on Natty?  I'll mark answered after I test.

Comment: I've retested and this did not resolve the incident on my system.  Thank you for the response though.

Comment: @krondor: I have a question to you: how is Citrix working on your Ubuntu system? I have here two 11.xx systems and it's no fun. Actually I even asked a question about the issue: [Citrix Ubuntu 11.10, focus problems](http://askubuntu.com/questions/84052/citrix-ubuntu-11-10-focus-problems)

Comment: @user694971: I haven't noticed too many problems, but I expect it is your compositing that is the culprit.  In 10.x I had problems with compositing and cube desktop.  If I spun the desktop Citrix window fell below the desktop (still running, but no longer usable).  Drove me crazy.  I'll keep an eye out for focus issues on drop down per your question.

Comment: @krondor: Thanks, that matches very much with my experience...

Answer (score 1):

## Use Getlibs

(You will find getlibs in [ppa:jcollins/jaminppa](https://launchpad.net/~jcollins/+archive/jaminppa))

```
getlibs -w  getlibs -w http://launchpadlibrarian.net/62541723/libmotif4_2.3.3-5ubuntu1_i386.deb/libmotif4_2.3.3-5_i386.deb

sudo ln -s /usr/lib/libXm.so.4 /usr/lib32/libXm.so.4
```

The ICA client should now start normally:

```
# /usr/lib/ICAClient/wfcmgr -icaroot /usr/lib/ICAClient
```

Comment: Thank you for the info, I'm going to do some more digging but it doesn't look like this PPA has a natty version.

Answer (score 0):

Use version 19.12 I cant get ANY versions later than this to work. I dont know if is related to what server my company is running so your mileage may vary.

Here is the download page, bit hard to find the pages for old versions.
https://www.citrix.com/downloads/workspace-app/legacy-workspace-app-for-linux/workspace-app-for-linux-1912.html