# Citrix client installation and configuration in ubuntu 11.10 or 12.04

Tags: 11.10, 12.04, citrix

Please tell me how to configure and install citrix client.

Detail procedure searched on Google not able to find any document on 11.10

Comment: Half a year later and user694971's answer got me on the right track :) Added in what I did for 12.04 and it was easier than I thought it would be. Thanks for the question Deepak :+

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install Citrix receiver?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/40723/how-do-i-install-citrix-receiver)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ironically in the last days I wrote an installation guide (using Citrix receiver), here are my steps:

Linux 32-bit

1. Get the Citrix Receiver from www.citrix.com -> Downloads -> Client Center -> Linux
2. Install it. You might get a warning this package has low quality.
3. Get OpenMotif, at least version 2.3.1: http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/non-free/o/openmotif/libmotif4_2.3.3-5_i386.deb
   (Warning: this does not work nicely, maybe because of compositing enabled. You might instead want to install OpenMotif via your Package Manager, e.g. Synaptic)
4. Now you should be able to start Citrix Receiver (Ubuntu: Applications -> Internet -> Citrix Receiver, in general/or to debug an error via gnome-terminal: /opt/Citrix/ICAClient/wfcmgr -icaroot /opt/Citrix/ICAClient)
5. Read below how to continue

Linux 64-bit

1. Get the Citrix Receiver from www.citrix.com -> Downloads -> Client Center -> Linux
2. Install it. You’ll probably get a warning this package has low quality. In fact this is a 32 bit package.
3. Get OpenMotif 32 bit, at least version 2.3.1 (taken from this guide)

   - wget http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/non-free/o/openmotif/libmotif4_2.3.3-5_i386.deb
     Extract the package
   - Ubuntu/Debian-based: dpkg -x libmotif4_2.3.3-5_i386.deb .
   - Copy lib files into your 32 bit compat lib folder:
   - Ubuntu/Debian-based: sudo cp -r usr/lib/* /usr/lib32/
     3a. sudo ldconfig
     3b. In case you have an Apparmor configuration, you might have to modify it
4. Now you should be able to start Citrix Receiver (Ubuntu: Applications -> Internet -> Citrix Receiver, in general: /opt/Citrix/ICAClient/wfcmgr -icaroot /opt/Citrix/ICAClient)
5. Read below how to continue

How to connect

1. Start Citrix Receiver
2. View -> Citrix XenApp View
3. Enter http:// hostname (make sure you can reach this address, e.g. test with ping; the hostname is the same hostname as for the Windows Online version, but leave the http path)
4. Afterwards enter your credentials like on Windows

My workstation is a 64-bit, unfortunately I hadn't had much opportunity to improve the 32-bit configuration steps. In fact I just posted a question on askubuntu regarding compositing: [Citrix Client on Ubuntu has focus problems](https://askubuntu.com/questions/84052/citrix-ubuntu-11-10-focus-problems)

Comment: It will great help if you can tell how connect where do  i put the address.is java required if yes which version

Comment: You're welcome. To connect you just have to follow "How to connect". At which point do you get stuck? But you don't need Java, the only thing required is OpenMotif.

Comment: where do i put the address.please it will great if you can give step step of how to connect

Comment: Just to clarify: you can use Citrix Receiver without a web browser. In case you want to use a browser, [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CitrixICAClientHowTo) is some info about it

Comment: Confusing i will try

Comment: Doing the 64 bit, after the copy, I had to run "sudo ldconfig -v" before it could find the new motif libraries.

Comment: I also had to modify my app-armor configuration.

Comment: @PaulTomblin: Thanks, I'll add that ldconfig and app-armor thing.

Comment: regarding libmotif: you can just apt-get install it and after I did a sudo ln -s /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/* /opt/Citrix/ICAClient/keystore/cacerts  I used Firefox to connect to our VPN. Worked like a charm :)

Answer (score 1):

The XenClient works like a live CD. You burn the .ISO image you downloaded from the site to a CD/DVD, boot the computer from it and follow the instructions.

If you're using Ubuntu 11.10, I suggest you do it virtually via [Virtualbox](http://www.virtualbox.org). That way you preserve your settings.

The instructions on the download page are sufficient. Here:

> **Instructions**
>
> Thank you for your interest in trying Citrix XenClient. To get started
>   with the evaluation software right away, please take the following
>   steps:
>
> **Step 1 - Prerequisites**
>
> - Please ensure that your laptop/desktop meets the [technical specifications and hardware compatibility list (HCL)](http://www.citrix.com/English/ps2/products/subfeature.asp?contentID=2300408) for running
>     XenClient on it.
> - If you intend to manage multiple XenClient computers with the Synchronizer for XenClient, you will need to have a server system
>     running XenServer 5.6 or higher. The Synchronizer for XenClient is
>     provided as a Xen Virtual Appliance (XVA) file, which can be imported
>     into XenServer. If you do not already have XenServer in your
>     environment, you will need to install XenServer onto a physical server
>     to host your Synchronizer. You can download [XenServer Free](http://www.citrix.com/lang/English/lp/lp_1688615.asp?ntref=try).
>
> **Step 2 - Software Downloads**
>
> - Download the XenClient file in the Download section above. Burn the ISO image onto an optical media.
> - Boot up the computer with the optical media and follow the instructions to install XenClient.
>
> Note: Back up all data on the computer prior to installing XenClient.
>   XenClient installs on the computer directly and erases any existing
>   software that was installed previously.
>
> **Step 3 - Configuration & Support**
>
> - Use the [Citrix XenClient 2 Setup and Usage Guide](http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX130401?ntref=Try).
> - Use the [CitrixClient 2 Synchronizer Setup and Usage Guide](http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX130403?ntref=Try).

Comment: only want configure client to connect to citrix server http://www.citrix.com/English/ss/downloads/details.asp?downloadId=2316611&productId=1689163

Answer (score 0):

> Ubuntu 12.04

- Download the DEB from http://www.citrix.com/English/ss/downloads/details.asp?downloadId=2323812&productId=1689163  (Receiver for Linux 3.39 MB.deb (x86 client - requires OpenMotif v.2.3.1))
- Install this file (mine was named `icaclient-12.1.0_i386.deb`) with Ubuntu Software Center (Nautilus, open with USC).
- Install libmotif4

  ```
  sudo apt-get install libmotif4
  ```
- Add Mozilla's certificates to Citrix ...

  ```
  sudo ln -s /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/* /opt/Citrix/ICAClient/keystore/cacerts
  ```
- Open Firefox and open the url for the VPN. Username, password, password from the key  and I could connect.