# Certificate error when using Citrix Receiver

Tags: 13.04, virtualization, certificates, citrix

I am getting this error when attempting to load a Desktop module up within Citrix Receiver:

[image]

What I don't understand is I can see this particular certificate is set to "Trust.." under any/all circumstances that I can find.  This only happens in Ubuntu, and I did not installed any certificates (manually) on either partition when trying to correct the issue.  The browser also appears to be irrelevant (Chrome/Firefox both generate the same error).  Forgive my ignorance on certificates, but this seems to be beyond my expertise.

There are a few places I've looked through various search engines, and I found other users who have had similar issues with certificates in the Linux Citrix Receiver, but I'm not sure what's wrong with this certificate, as none of the other suggestions I've tried have worked so far, and they're too numerous to go into detail... so I'd like to take it from here and see what you all can offer up.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

To prevent the SSL error 61 when accessing remote sessions:

Make Firefox's certificates accessible to Citrix,

```
sudo ln -s /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/* /opt/Citrix/ICAClient/keystore/cacerts
sudo /opt/Citrix/ICAClient/util/ctx_rehash
```

<sup>Source: Citrix help page</sup>

Comment: Worked like a charm.  Don't know how I missed this on Citrix's own site, I guess I was looking too much at user-centric help/forums.

Comment: Works on Linux Mint 18 based on Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: I did a copy instead of symbolic link. Works good. I copied only the certificate it complained about --> `sudo cp /etc/ssl/certs/DigiCert_High_Assurance_EV_Root_CA.pem /opt/Citrix/ICAClient/keystore/cacerts/` --- Using Citrix Receiver Full 13.6 on Ubuntu 16.04.3

Comment: Note @marlon 's comment: After copying/linking you must run `sudo /opt/Citrix/ICAClient/util/ctx_rehash`

Comment: Works on Linux Mint 19 (Ubuntu 18.04) (I had to both link the files and run ctx_rehash) and then it worked perfectly

Comment: Still relevant and working for Ubuntu 19.10

Comment: This fixed "0.0.0.2 No such file or directory" error for me. Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: You might need to run `sudo /opt/Citrix/ICAClient/util/ctx_rehash` for the latest version of the workspace app.

Comment: Another year, another change to the citrix app. Now you also need to run `sudo ln -s /etc/ssl/certs/* /opt/Citrix/ICAClient/keystore/cacerts`, because it wants the certificates in `pem` format instead. After this, run the rehash function again.

Answer (score 8):

Newer versions of the receiver require you to <s>convert the `CRT` file to `PEM`</s>, place the crt in a specific directory, and run a citrix utility.

If your installation is in `/opt/Citrix/ICAClient` and assuming the signing root certificate or CA is an existing one in ca-certificates:

1. Get to the certificates directory:

```bsh
cd /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/
```

<s>2. Convert the desired `CRT` to `PEM` :</s>

```bash
sudo openssl x509 -outform pem -in [SIGNING_CERTIFICATE_YOU_ID_FROM_COMPANY_WEBSITE.crt] -out [NEW_CERT_PICK_YOUR_NAME.pem]
```

3. Link it to the Citrix directory and rehash:

```bash
sudo ln -s NEW_CERT /opt/Citrix/ICAClient/keystore/cacerts/
cd /opt/Citrix/ICAClient/util
sudo ./ctx_rehash
```

If the CA is not a known and trusted one present in the `/usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla` directory mentioned above:

1. Download it using your browser's security info on the site
2. <s>Convert it to `PEM`</s> Move it, and rehash: Step 3 above.

Left the crossed out text for anyone needing those instructions for whatever reason but I recently tested just moving the CRT to the directory and the rehash utility will convert as needed.

Comment: The `sudo /opt/Citrix/ICAClient/util/ctx_rehash` bit did it for me (Skipped the conversion with`sudo openssl ...`, though my export appears to be a pem)

Comment: For me, the pem trick worked once (thanks). But not after the reboot.
I tried again the same steps, no more luck.
I reverted to icaclient 13.4 and it just works. Looks like verions >13.4 are broken.

Comment: Not broken but rather they changed they way they worked to be more secure.  If that didn't work the second time then something else is the cause?  I use the client daily and it works just fine.  As long as your company wont require a specific version higher than 13.4 you can keep it.

Answer (score 4):

some users (like me) might find that even after linking Firefox to the cacerts folder the error persists.

That appears to be because Citrix does not supply all of the latest certificates.

The solution appears to be to note the certificate said to be "not trusted" (eg "Verisign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5") then export it from Firefox (under the Preferences menu then Certificates) to */ICAClient/keystore/cacerts.

Worked for me.  Hope this helps.

Comment: so close yet so far!  No joy for me I'm afraid

Comment: if the certificate is in PEM this works, if not look at my answer.

Answer (score 2):

a bit late to the discussion, but found the below to work for version 23.3.0.32.  got this from Peter Smith's answer [here](https://discussions.citrix.com/topic/417466-citrix-workspace-linux-229021-ssl-error/).  i was having a difficult time with .crt vs .pem certificate extensions and this resolved my issue.

```
sudo rm -rfv /opt/Citrix/ICAClient/keystore/cacerts
cd /opt/Citrix/ICAClient/keystore/    
sudo ln -s /etc/ssl/certs cacerts
/opt/Citrix/ICAClient/util/ctx_rehash
```

Comment: That did it for me! Lifesaver, as my company is moving an important part of work from remote desktop to citrix

Answer (score 0):

I've the same error, but with a certificates trusted by my FireFox. So after copy the root ca certificate and converted these in crt files, the ICA client run without problem.
Hope this info will be useful

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and solved it this way:

1. Place certificate to be trusted in `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates`
2. Execute `sudo update-ca-certificates` 
   You should see something line this:
   `1 added, 0 removed; done.
   Running hooks in /etc/ca-certificates/update.d....
   Adding debian:SymantecClass3SecureServerCA-G4.pem`
3. Use Google Chrome instead of Firefox