# How to configure Citrix Receiver started through Cisco Secure Desktop on Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: 15.10, rdp, cisco, citrix

Many Corporations enables to work from home using Secure RDP approach to the Windows systems. But how to start it on Linux, wen in Corporation is no support for Linux Citrix RDP? When I click on RDP Client, there were error Citrix Receiver

[image]

or nothing happened.

Configuration:

- Ubuntu 15.10 (Compiz)
- Firefox 42.0
- Citrix Receiver for Linux (icaclient 13.2.1)

Answer (score 0):

I received the same error message ever after working my way through https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CitrixICAClientHowTo

Try making Firefox's certificates accessible to Citrix:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/* /opt/Citrix/ICAClient/keystore/cacerts
```

This worked for me.

Also take a look at this link:

[Certificate error when using Citrix Receiver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/302188/certificate-error-when-using-citrix-receiver)