# SSL Error 61 in Citrix Receiver in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ssl

I am using Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS and I have Citrix Receiver installed.
When I am trying to login, I got the error:

> You have not chosen to trust "DigiCert Hish Assurance Server CA", the issuer of the server's security certificate (SSL error 61)"

So, I tried installing certificate, and when I try to copy and rehash the certificate to `/Citrix/ICAClient/keystore/cacerts/` I got the error:

```
unable to load certificate
140085276386976:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:pem_lib.c:696:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE
DigiCertSHA2HighAssuranceServerCA.crt => .0
unable to load certificate
140703055140512:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:pem_lib.c:696:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE
WARNING: Skipping duplicate certificate DigiCertSHA2HighAssuranceServerCA.crt
```

What is the solution for this kind of problem?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Certificate error when using Citrix Receiver](http://askubuntu.com/questions/302188/certificate-error-when-using-citrix-receiver)

Answer (score 1):

Just go ahead and copy certificates from Mozilla's folder into the Citrix certs folders

```
sudo ln -s /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/* /opt/Citrix/ICAClient/keystore/cacerts
```

This should do the work for you!

[Source](https://askubuntu.com/a/302322/596545)

Comment: This worked for me on Ubuntu on `Distributor ID:Ubuntu,Description:Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS,Release:20.04Codename:focal`