# Ubuntu 15.10 - Citrix Receiver - SSL error 61

Tags: firefox, 15.10, ssl, citrix

The following Error occures when trying to use Citrix (access SAP Training via Citrix) on Ubuntu 15.10:

Citrix Receiver
 
**SSL error**
Contact your helpdesk with th following inofrmation:
 You have not chosen to trust "Symantec Class 3 Secure Server CA / G4", the issuer of ther server's security certificate (SSL error 61).

[image: Citrix SSL Error Message]

I installed Citrix according the Tutorial [How to install Citrix Receiver icaclient in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64-bit](https://mark911.wordpress.com/2014/06/27/how-to-install-citrix-receiver-icaclient-in-ubuntu-14-04-lts-64-bit-tested-and-working-using-mozilla-firefox/) The installation completed without any errors.

I also made sure that the certificates are there according to the [CitrixXenAppPlugin - configure certificates](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CitrixXenAppPlugin):

[image]

Additionally I checked in Firefox if the certificates are known and even checked all marks (which where not checked before) (Under Settings -> Advanced -> Certificates):

[image: Firefox Certificate settings]

What am I missing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Certificate error when using Citrix Receiver](http://askubuntu.com/questions/302188/certificate-error-when-using-citrix-receiver)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution 1**

OK thx to the hints from @sletarte here the solution:

1. Place certificate to be trusted in `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates`
2. Execute `sudo update-ca-certificates` 
   You should see something line this:
   `1 added, 0 removed; done. Running hooks in /etc/ca-certificates/update.d.... Adding debian:SymantecClass3SecureServerCA-G4.pem`
3. Use Google Chrome instead of Firefox

**Solution 2**

Follow the steps from [Citrix Workspace App for Linux: How to trust a CA certificate?](https://support.citrix.com/article/CTX231524)

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.1, Firefox 50 and Citrix Receiver 13.4.

@thorsten-niehues solution didn't work for me unfortunately.

To solve the problem, I had to copy the `.crt` file to `/opt/Citrix/ICAClient/keystore/cacerts`

I was then able to connect to Citrix with Firefox and with Chrome without any problem.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what scripts are run in your Citrix install, but I believe you may still need to tell Ubuntu to trust the root CA - you can do that by running *sudo dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates* from the directory where you have the .crt files for Citrix.  mozilla has its own directory (/usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla) and that may be where it is looking to show the list of trusted certs that you see in Firefox.

Comment: Thanks for the Information. Unfortunately it did not solve the Issue. In /opt/Citrix/ICAClient/keystore/cacerts are symlinks to /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla so I tried the command in both directories with no success :( I also tried copy the certificate in both directories with no success.

Comment: @ThorstenNiehues - sorry - been a while since I've done this on Ubuntu -- have you tried update-ca-certificates?  Good manpage description for that command.