# Problem with server access by error in certificate

Tags: firefox, certificates, citrix

I access a virtual machine for work through Citrix. When I log in from Ubuntu I get the same error from Firefox and Chromium (I've also tried it from Fedora, Mandriva, OpenSUSE, Debian ... and with all it goes the same): a certificate error Symantec Error SSL 61.

Testing from the Symantec SSL Certificate Test page, it tells me that the error is that my certificate is badly installed on the server. I do not think that is possible, as I see that the problem also happens with Windows, but that this is probably ignored due to the level of security that I use for Internet surfing. I think that in Ubuntu there could be something that obviates this error.

That is, with any browser from Windows, although it should trigger the same problem, it does not prevent me from connecting to the server. But from Ubuntu the connection is rejected. Are there any security settings at the operating system level in Ubuntu that allow me to "skip this error" as happens with Windows? As you will see I have done countless tests to troubleshoot the error and I think I have identified it, but I am not an expert in Ubuntu and I do not know how I can solve it.

I also did what the answers at [Ubuntu 15.10 - Citrix Receiver - SSL error 61](https://askubuntu.com/questions/746342/ubuntu-15-10-citrix-receiver-ssl-error-61) say, and nothing happened. That is because the problem is not in my computer but in the Server certificate installation. I cannot change this installation but, because it works in Windows, I think I can change something in my Ubuntu system to solve this problem. Thanks.

<sub>[**Original Spanish text here.**](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/876845/1)</sub>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu 15.10 - Citrix Receiver - SSL error 61](http://askubuntu.com/questions/746342/ubuntu-15-10-citrix-receiver-ssl-error-61)

Comment: Thanks. Certainly... but I did what post says and nothing happend. That is because the problem is not in my computer but in the Server certificate installation. I cannot change this installation but because it works in Windows, I think I can change something in my Ubuntu to solve this problem. Thanks.