# Citrix ICA receiver on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: 17.10, citrix

I had successfully been using Citrix ICA client 13.3 on Ubuntu 16.04 for quite a while.  Recently I bought a new laptop and installed Ubuntu 17.10.  I installed the latest 13.7 Citrix .deb, updated the SSL certificates etc and tried to login.  However, I got some unfamiliar SSL error (4).  After checking some forums I decided to try 13.4.  I started off with

```
sudo apt-get remove icaclient
```

After that I installed the 13.4 deb.  However, I got the same error and noticed there were still stray files left from 13.7, so I tried to completely remove them manually, as below

```
sudo rm -rf /etc/icaclient/
sudo rm -rf /etc/icalicense/
rm -rf ~/.ICAClient/
```

I then tried to reinstall 13.4 but it would not even load, complaining of missing .ini files (module.ini, regions.ini etc).  I tried touching some and the receiver loaded, but of course complained about invalid keyboard mapping etc.  I have come to the conclusion there are still some ICA files on my laptop and I need to delete them before proceeding.  Can anyone tell me where they are?

After that, any tips fixing SSL error 4 on Ubuntu 17.10?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try icaclient 13.6.

I had the same error with 13.7 and downgraded to 13.6. I don't have this issue with 13.6 anymore.

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately the problem is that now no versions of the client will run because (I believe) there are some orphan config files somewhere

Comment: Ok, the first problem is solved- I should have *purged* the package not simply removed it.  Unfortunately I still get the error with icaclient 13.6 and will try 13.4

Comment: I had to go back to 13.3 and then it worked! :o

Answer (score 1):

That is not needed.  You can use the latest version just follow my answer here: [Certificate error when using Citrix Receiver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/302188/certificate-error-when-using-citrix-receiver/971510?s=1|0.0000#971510)

Newer versions of the receiver require you to run their util and move the cert as a PEM certificate not the default CRT included with Mozilla ca-certificates.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll give it a try when I next upgrade.  However, it should be noted that the SSL error I had was *not* that I didn't trust the server (as in the linked question).

Comment: it doesnt matter if you trust it.  Citrix Receiver comes with its own certificates that it trusts.  You can see that at /opt/Citrix/ICAClient/keystore/cacerts/ if you installed it to /opt as default.  So your browsers will still work normally.

Answer (score 1):

Just succesfully installed the citrix client on a fresh ubuntu 17.10, using google chrome.

Download the Citrix Receiver for Linux from:  https://www.citrix.com/downloads/citrix-receiver/linux/
Choose the debian packages, webclient only, architecture type depending on your cpu.

Install the package by clicking it (or from the command line if you prefer to type)

Add SSL certificates by executing the following two commands from the command line:

sudo ln -s /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/* /opt/Citrix/ICAClient/keystore/cacerts/

sudo c_rehash /opt/Citrix/ICAClient/keystore/cacerts/

You can now use your webclient.

Resources: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CitrixICAClientHowTo

Comment: Ta, that worked for me on Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to my first question about removing orphan configuration files is to *purge* the package rather than simply remove it, e.g.

```
sudo dpkg -P icaclient
```

Then I tried 13.6 (didn't work).  Then 13.4 (didn't work).  Finally 13.3, which I had before (did work).