# Cannot install icaclient due to problem with ia32-libs

Tags: apt, 64-bit, dependencies

**Finally, Citrix released a new version and Ubuntu updated their guide [HERE](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CitrixICAClientHowTo) (apparently, it were the dependecy changes as we found out). It should work now kind of out of the box.**

---

I have a problem installing the package `icaclient` on 13.10 Saucy Salamander 64bit. It seems that there is a problem with ia32-libs and other dependencies.

```
 marc@PinballWizard:~$ sudo dpkg -i Downloads/icaclient_12.1.0_amd64.deb
 [sudo] password for marc: 
 Selecting previously unselected package icaclient.
 (Reading database ... 179461 files and directories currently installed.)
 Unpacking icaclient (from .../icaclient_12.1.0_amd64.deb) ...
 dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of icaclient:
  icaclient depends on ia32-libs; however:
   Package ia32-libs is not installed.
  icaclient depends on lib32z1; however:
   Package lib32z1 is not installed.
  icaclient depends on lib32asound2; however:
   Package lib32asound2 is not installed.

 dpkg: error processing icaclient (--install):
  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
 Errors were encountered while processing:
  icaclient
```

Hence, other workarounds seem not to work. I followed the instructions [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CitrixICAClientHowTo) - and for the last two Ubuntu releases it was surely no problem.

When I try to install ia32-libs I get the following issue:

```
marc@PinballWizard:~$ sudo apt-get install ia32-libs 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package ia32-libs is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0

E: Package 'ia32-libs' has no installation candidate
```

Is there any possibility to install `icaclient`?

The sources.list is [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/6245853/).

Comment: Hope this will Bring your issue to get fixed 

[Click here][1]


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/40723/how-do-i-install-citrix-receiver

Comment: Hm, they only link to the official documentation which does not work for me with saucy...

Comment: `ia32-libs` has been obsolete since 11.10. It used to consist of a single large collection of 32-bit libraries, but with the addition of multi-arch support packages should now depend on package:architecture pairs, eg `libbz2-1.0:i386`. You could perhaps edit the package's control file with new dependencies, but the source package needs to be updated. Alternatively, you might just be able to install the ..._i386.deb 32-bit version directly.

Comment: (see http://askubuntu.com/questions/107230/what-happened-to-the-ia32-libs-package for more about ia32-libs/multiarch)

Comment: I found a solution here: http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-2166020.html

Answer (score 3):

There is a way under 13.10 brought to us by dark_harmonics on [ubuntuforums](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-2166020.html) (last post) - I just quote him here:

> Just to document this process so that when i google this problem i
>   come across the compiled solution to this:
>
> 1. Download citrix deb file from www.citrix.com. I used the new customer preview 12.9.999
> 2. Open a terminal and change to the directory where the deb file is located
> 3. Run the following commands
>
>    ```
>    mkdir ica_temp
>    dpkg-deb -x icaclient-<tab> ica_temp
>    dpkg-deb --control icaclient-<tab> ica_temp/DEBIAN
>    sudo gedit ica_temp/DEBIAN/control
>    ```
> 4. Change the dependencies to be "Depends: libc6-i386 (>= 2.7-1), lib32z1, nspluginwrapper"
> 5. Save and close the file
> 6. Compile and install the deb file
>
>    ```
>    dpkg -b ica_temp icaclient-modified.deb
>    sudo dpkg -i icaclient-modified.deb
>    ```
> 7. Cleanup with
>
>    ```
>    rm -r ica_temp
>    ```
>
> I also needed to run `sudo apt-get install -f` to install the dependencies I was still missing.

BTW: Customer Preview did not work for me, I used the official version.

Comment: I followed these steps and installed without errors, but I'm still missing the 32-bit version of libXp.so.6.  `ldd /opt/Citrix/ICAClient/wfcmgr` gives as only missing dependency `libXp.so.6 => not found`. I do have the 64-bit version in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXp.so.6`

Comment: Ok, `sudo apt-get install libXp6:i386` solved it

Comment: `sudo apt-get -f install` installs missing dependencies... That was the clue for me.

Comment: I also had to do the following step from the [CitrixICAClientHowto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CitrixICAClientHowTo) :`[Change] line 2648 in ica_temp/DEBIAN/postinst:

echo $Arch|grep "i[0-9]86" >/dev/null

to:
echo $Arch|grep -E "i[0-9]86|x86_64" >/dev/null`

Answer (score 1):

I have a x64bit system

You have to edit out dependecies: ia23-libs and libaudio32 from the .deb package.

Create `/dir_tmp` and `/dir_tmp/DEBIAN`

```
dpkg-deb -x foo.deb dir_tmp
dpkg-deb --control foo.deb dir_tmp/DEBIAN
```

Edit `/dir_tmp/DEBIAN/control`  and delete the dependencies.

```
dpkg -b dir_tmp foo.deb
```

Try install ICAclient again

If you get an exit status 2, please try:

Edit `/var/lib/dpkg/info/icaclient.postinst`

Find: `echo $Arch|grep "i[0-9]86" >/dev/null` and change it to `echo $Arch|grep -E "i[0-9]86|x86_64" >/dev/null`

If you get a SSL error when running Citrix reciver, try:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/* /opt/Citrix/ICAClient/keystore/cacerts/
```

Answer (score 1):

These instructions works in Ubuntu 13.04 and prior:

1. Get the official [Citrix Receiver 12.1](https://www.citrix.com/downloads/citrix-receiver/receivers-by-platform/receiver-for-linux-121.html) 64-bits .deb package. Make sure you grab the 64-bits one.
2. Install `gdebi`:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install gdebi
   ```
3. Run `sudo gdebi Downloads/icaclient_12.1.0_amd64.deb` the installer will ask you if you wants to install the package along all dependencies:

   ```
   Citrix Receiver for Linux
    The Citrix Receiver for Linux provides users with access to resources published
    on XenApp or XenDesktop servers. The clients combine ease of deployment and
    use, and offer quick, secure access to applications, content, and virtual
    desktops.
    .
    Users can connect to resources published on XenApp servers using either
    individual ICA connections or, if using Citrix XenApp, predefined ICA
    connection configurations from servers running the Web Interface.
    .
    Users can also connect to virtual desktops provided by XenDesktop, enabling
    them to use those virtual desktops as if they were connecting to a local
    Windows desktop.
   Do you want to install the software package? [y/N]:
   ```

   Select `y` then hit enter. Done.

This method has the advantage that doesn't require user intervention and resolves dependencies almost flawlessly.

While it resolves dependencies, the package itself has other issues:

```
dpkg: error processing icaclient (--install):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 icaclient
```

Furtulately, there is a solution:

```
sudo sed -i 's/grep \"i\[0\-9\]86\"/grep -E "i[0-9]86|x86_64"/g' /var/lib/dpkg/info/icaclient.postinst
sudo dpkg --configure icaclient
```

Citrix doesn't have that many certificates, so when you access your site, you can get SSL errors. If you have mozilla certificates, add them:

```
 sudo ln -s /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/* /opt/Citrix/ICAClient/keystore/cacerts/
```

References: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CitrixICAClientHowTo

Comment: Are you sure that it resolves dependencies? I get `Dependency is not satisfiable: ia32-libs` when trying to do `sudo gdebi Downloads/icaclient_12.1.0_amd64.deb`

Comment: Just again: I cannot install via gdebi. I get the above mentioned dependency error, what makes me unable to install icaclient.

Answer (score 1):

Change the dependencies to be "Depends: libc6-i386 (>= 2.7-1), lib32z1, nspluginwrapper"
Save and close the file
Compile and install the deb file

Should be:
**Depends: libc6-i386 (>= 2.7-1), lib32asound2:i386, nspluginwrapper**

Comment: This is sufficient to answer the questions, but Braiam's response also includes instructions on how to complete the installation once you finish this step.

Answer (score 0):

I followed [this how-to on the Ubuntu Community Help Wiki.](http://help.ubuntu.com/community/CitrixICAClientHowTo) It worked fine for me.

Comment: So they finally updated the page - and Citrix updated their receiver. Should work now.