# "Command not found" when running a program

Tags: command-line, permissions

I downloaded the Citrix receiver for Linux 13.0 (I'm running Ubuntu 13.10 64bits) from http://www.citrix.com/downloads/citrix-receiver/linux/receiver-for-linux-130.html.

I unpacked it using alien, but when I tried to open the receiver from the command line (as explained in the documentation) by typing /opt/Citrix/ICAClient/selfservice it told me "Command not found". I tried to navigate to the folder from the graphical interface: I could see the file (which is of type application/x-executable) but when I double clicked on it nothing happened!

I tried to right click and check the permissions: the executable case was ticked but it told me that I cannot modify anything because I am not the owner... I also tried chmod from the command line but nothing changed. Does anybody know why this is happening?

Comment: Are you sure that your system is on 64 bit? If yes, did you downloaded Citrix Receiver for 64-bit systems? Have you read the [System requirements](http://support.citrix.com/proddocs/topic/receiver-linux-13-0/linux-sys-reqs.html) and all [other documentation](http://support.citrix.com/proddocs/topic/infocenter/ic-how-to-use.html)?

Comment: I checked with synaptics and all the required packages seem to be installed... it's so annoying I double click on the icon and nothing happens, if at least I got an error message I would at least know where to start!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install Citrix receiver?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/40723/how-do-i-install-citrix-receiver)