# Ubuntu 13.10 doesn't let Citrix (icaclient) run

Tags: upgrade, citrix

For years, on Ubuntu 10.04, 11.10, 12.04, 12.10, and 13.04, I have been able to access my workplace using Citrix (icaclient).

After the OS upgrade:

1. If I use Firefox, everything that I try to do that requires Citrix causes the browser to grey out as if overloaded. It eventually goes back to where it had been exactly at the point where I tried to activate Citrix.
2. If I use Google Chromium, and try to activate (use) Citrix, the browser doesn't recognise "launch.ica" and tries to download it instead of opening it.

I have tried to install the Citrix again from [here](https://www.citrix.com/downloads/citrix-receiver/legacy-client-software/receiver-for-linux-121.html) (for 64-bit systems), and when I try to install "Receiver for Linux" (using the .deb file in Ubuntu Software Centre), I receive the error message "Cannot install 'lib32z1'".

Any ideas how I might get Citrix (icaclient) running again?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install Citrix receiver?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/40723/how-do-i-install-citrix-receiver)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A-ha!

I can't remember how I found it now, but the answer is [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CitrixICAClientHowTo). I found that "how to" (for which I created that link) for through the answer to [this AskUbuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/107230/what-happened-to-the-ia32-libs-package).