# Has anyone been able to get the Citrix Receiver running on Ubuntu 14.04 64bit?

Tags: 14.04, citrix

I have installed the Citrix Receiver 13.0.0.256735 as described for Ubuntu 13.10 here: [CitrixICAClientHowTo](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CitrixICAClientHowTo)

The installation has succeded under Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit. But if I start the Citrix Receiver nothing happens.

Is there someone who has it running with Ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: I am running it under linux. [Directions to install are in Ubuntu help web site.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CitrixICAClientHowTo) The programs run but no matter what I do in the configuration I can not move the citrix windows around...

Comment: I used the same directions you advised. And I run the Citrix Receiver with Ubuntu 12.10 64 bit flawless. My problems started with version 14.04 64 bit of Ubuntu. Which Linux do you use?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install Citrix receiver?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/40723/how-do-i-install-citrix-receiver)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me: http://www.tuxtrix.com/2013/11/how-to-install-citrix-receiver-13-on.html

If `apt-get` gives you any errors along the lines of "The following packages have unmet dependencies:" remember to `sudo dpkg -P icaclient`.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I reinstalled all again following the instructions from above. Now it is working. But only when I start the applications from the browser. In earlier Versions it was possible to start the desktops and applications from the start menu.

Comment: The link is dead. Bad - link only answer.

Answer (score 3):

I followed the below steps and it worked for me:

1. Download Citrix for Linux 64 bit from http://www.citrix.com/downloads/citrix-receiver/linux/receiver-for-linux-130.html
2. Follow instructions in "Citrix Receiver 12.1 on Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit" section from 
   https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CitrixICAClientHowTo
3. In case of any Verisign certificate errors, export the certificates mentioned in the errors (eg: VeriSign Class 3 International Server CA - G3) from Mozilla Firefox: *Edit* > *Preferences* > *Advanced* > *Encryption* > *View Certificates*, and browse the list to find the VeriSign entries.
4. Export the ones that are Class 3, one by one, in X509 format (PEM), and store them in your "cacert" folder with the `.crt` extension (you have to manually add the extension when you save the certificates). Copy it to `/opt/Citrix/ICAClient/keystore/cacerts/`.

Refer  http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1143029.html for more details.

Comment: Why hasn't Citrix automated the certificate installation in their installer?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
sudo apt-get install libmotif4:i386 nspluginwrapper lib32z1 libc6-i386 libxp6:i386 libxpm4:i386 libasound2:i386
```

from: https://www.citrix.com/downloads/citrix-receiver/receivers-by-platform/receiver-for-linux-121.html

Note: Get the download from the "For 64-bit Systems" section. If the Download popup doesn't work in Chrome, use Firefox.

```
cd ~/Downloads
mkdir ica_temp
dpkg-deb -x icaclient_12.1.0_amd64.deb ica_temp
dpkg-deb --control icaclient_12.1.0_amd64.deb ica_temp/DEBIAN
sudo gedit ica_temp/DEBIAN/control

sudo dpkg -i icaclient-modified.deb

sudo ln -s /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/* /opt/Citrix/ICAClient/keystore/cacerts

/opt/Citrix/ICAClient/wfcmgr &
```

*For the full tutorial click [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CitrixICAClientHowTo). *

Comment: A critical part of the instructions is missing: what to change in the file opened with gedit.