# Citrix Client 11

Tags: 14.04, citrix

How to install Citrix Client **version 11** on **Ubuntu 14.04.** I need only Citrix version 11, not another one.
I tryed to use documentation on CitrixICAClientHowTo but it doesn't help

Comment: Have you seen http://askubuntu.com/questions/462977/does-anyone-got-the-citrix-receiver-running-on-ubuntu-14-04-64

Comment: I need to install Citrix client 11, only version 11. I have never seen anybody install this version on Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: I believe this is useful https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CitrixICAClientHowToOlderVersions

Comment: It would help if you talk about what you've tried so far and where you're currently stuck. Mind too, citrix receiver client 11 is pretty old. I understand sometimes use of legacy software is out of your control, but are you *sure* 13 won't work?