# Cannot locate packages for Citrix install

Tags: apt, 14.04, software-installation, citrix

I'm trying to get a Citrix receiver installed on to Ubuntu 14.04 (64 bit) following Ubuntu's [docs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CitrixICAClientHowTo#Citrix_Receiver_12.1_on_Ubuntu_14.04_64-bit). The first line of instructions say to get these required packages:

```
sudo apt-get install libmotif4:i386 nspluginwrapper lib32z1 libc6-i386 libxp6:i386 libxpm4:i386 libasound2:i386
```

But if I paste in that line, I get this error:

```
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libmotif4
E: Unable to locate package libxp6
E: Unable to locate package libxpm4
E: Unable to locate package libasound2
```

My repository settings are below. Is there anything I'm missing in there? Otherwise what do I need to do to install these?

```
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 14.04 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20140417)]/ precise main restricted
deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 14.04 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20140417)]/ trusty main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main restricted #Added by software-properties
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted universe multiverse #Added by software-properties
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security main restricted universe multiverse #Added by software-properties
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted universe multiverse #Added by software-properties
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-proposed main universe restricted multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main universe restricted multiverse
```

Comment: What's in `/etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/architectures`?

Comment: Do `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386; apt-get update`

Comment: @bain That was it! Thanks very much. For the sake of people searching (and I'd imagine - like me - you might like the StackExchange credits :o) do you want to add that as an answer?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install Citrix receiver?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/40723/how-do-i-install-citrix-receiver)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not have multiarch enabled. Do:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
```