# Citrix opens and closes in Ubuntu

Tags: networking, server, citrix

I installed Ubuntu 14.04, this updated and installed directly from the icaclient Receiver site.
installation occurred without error, as I use the external address of the citrix ex: external link ee performs normal however when I run the internal address eg 192.168.0.1 or internal link, it opens the connection screen and closes.
Note: it normally logs in citrix, and when we go on desktops it opens the desktop only if connected by the external server, the internal server it does not connect.
I look forward to help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install Citrix receiver?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/40723/how-do-i-install-citrix-receiver)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the browser does not know what to launch with the .ica file in Ubuntu.

I used the following article link to get my Citrix Client to Work in Ubuntu 13.10. I've since upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit and haven't tried to install Citrix yet, but try this to see if it will work in Ubuntu 14.04. Also, for further follow up, it would be helpful to know if you're using the 32-bit version or 64-bit version of Ubuntu.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CitrixICAClientHowTo

I do know the regular client did not work for me (Citrix Receiver), I had to download and install the Web Client (XenApp).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using google-chrome you will also have to physically click the launch.ica file that is downloaded each time. It will not automatically open even if you associate the ica file with the citrix receiver as I have.