# How to start Citrix client in Chrome/Chromium?

Tags: 14.04, 64-bit, google-chrome, chromium, citrix

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 (64) and Chromium 43.0.2357.81. But when I log in to the customer, the file launch.ica is downloaded but the Citrix app doesn't start automatically. But if I go to the drive, mark the file and open it with "Citrix Receiver Engine", everything is working. The file launch.ica has its properties set to "Always open" with "citrix Receiver Engine". When i run Firefox, same computer, OS and so on, everything is working correct.
I've run the following command several times.

xdg-mime default wfica.desktop application/x-ica

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will make Chrome/Chromium open the file directly:

After downloading the ica file, click on the arrow next to the file name (in Chrome). This opens a menu, try the second item: Open, **Always open files of this type** (click this), Show in folder, Cancel

Next time, it will open the file.